# Mac OS terminal doesn't find commands

Tags: macos, terminal

I have weird problem as all of the sudden terminal stopped reading any commands. Last weekend I installed Wordpress with PHP and mySQL and since that moment didn't have time to do anything more on laptop. Now I wanted to launch some react-native code but command wasn't found, then I tried different things to use some other commands and each time I get message

> MBP-Mateusz-2:business-cards-native mateusz$ code .
>
> -bash: code: command not found

and doesn't matter what command is that except standard ones like ls, cd etc. However when I try to write npm --version, or node --version, or launch visual studio code like before with code ., each time I get command not found. Doesn't anyone have issue like that? How to fix it as I'm super confused and have no idea even where to start.

Comment: if you type the full path `/usr/local/bin/npm` does it work? Exactly what does it say if you open a fresh terminal window and type `echo $PATH`?

Comment: hey thanks for reply, when I type echo $PATH It shows
```/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin```,
and when I want to get to usr/local/bin/npm it says it doesn't exist, I tried to get there manually and when I get /usr/local, I have only two files , ```mysql``` and ```mysql-8.0.15-macos10.14-x86_64```

Comment: you tried `/usr/local/bin/npm`, right, not `usr/local/bin/npm`? (the initial `/` is important) If so, then it sounds like your `npm` got removed somehow?? Your `PATH` is doubled up (everything repeated), but should still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably messed up your `PATH` environment variable, and now your computer cannot find the commands if you don't tell it directly where. The PATH variable contains the directories where the system should look for binaries if they're not in the current directory. If it gets corrupted for some reason, you won't be able to run any program from the terminal unless you pointed directly its location.

I would first run this command:

```
echo $PATH
```

so you can see which is the content of the PATH.

If it seems empty, or some critical folders are missing, try to add them  temporarily:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Then try to run the commands again from the same terminal and see if that worked.

If that works, check if you have a `~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist` file and its content. It is possible that there is a key for the PATH and that its values are pointing something of your Wordpress stack but not the system directories.

If that looks fine, look at the `~/.bash_profile` file. Find any `export PATH` instruction that may explain your issues. If you can't find any, but still exporting the PATH worked out, add at the end of the file that instruction as a workaround for fixing the mess:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

(notice that I'm ading $PATH in this last case so if there is any other path actually configured it is added as well)

Good luck.

---

**EDIT:** That's the usual issue people has, but now that I've read your comments, the issue seems a bit more serious. It looks like the mySQL setup destroyed your `/usr/local/` folder, which means you lost all the binaries located there `npm`, `code`, etc.

- If you have a backup of the whole filesystem (which by experience is unlikely), restore `/usr/local` folder.
- If you don't have any backups, you can reconstruct `/usr/local`... by reinstalling the software that cannot be found. Reinstall npm, VSCode, etc, that will place their executables again in the `/usr/local` folders and from there you'll be good to go. Install [brew](https://brew.sh/) (since it's likely that also got deleted) then try `brew install node` and see if now you can run `npm`. If that works out, I'm afraid you'll have to reinstall all the software you lost again.

Comment: oki I tried as you said but it doesn't seem to work, I added this path and now it looks like 
```/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin```
but when I try commands like npm --version or node --version it still shows command not found,
Before my path actually shows on some mysql folder, like this 
```/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin```

Comment: yeah now it works... eh I always disliked mySQL and now I dislike it even more... any idea why it could happen like that? What I could do wrong while installing it that it removed all other files in local? And also thank you friend for help, so it's gonna be long weekend to install everything

Comment: It's weird. The most likely thing is some wrong use of `rm` that has lead to this accident. It could also be something as weird as a wrong order in `mv` command when trying to move some extracted files, something like `mv /usr/local ~/Downloads/mysql` instead of the proper `mv ~/Downloads/mysql /usr/local/`... or some other weird thing. Make a global search for npm in your hard disk... maybe you did actually move it _somewhere_.

Comment: I tried to find it by 'find' command but nah, It was gone permanently or hidden very well, hmm I try to watch out with rm and don't remember to use mv but maybe, it was last weekend when I install Wordpress and rest and maybe don't remember it... Anyway now when I mingle with something close to /usr/local I will try to have a copy of that file somewhere